# getting text after html tag with php and xpath

Tags: php, html, xpath

I have the following html from a curl scrap of a webpage:

```
<div id="box">
<br>
Your word(s):
<br>
<br>
functionally
<br>
<br>
<br>
```

I want what is after the third `<br>`: `/html/body/div[2]/div/br[3]` - that being **functionality**

```
@$itemCell = $xpath->query( "/html/body/div[2]/div/br[3]" );
$word = $itemCell->item( 0 );
return $word->nodeValue;
```

this does not return anything. If I back up to just `/div` I of course get the entire contents of **box**. How do I extract the word after the second `<br>`. My word is always going to be after the third `<br>`.

Seems so simple, yet it escapes me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this query

```
$textNodes = $xpath->query('//div[@id="box"]/br[3]/following-sibling::text()[1]');
```

Working demo here - http://codepad.viper-7.com/00oeZh

The key here is the `following-sibling` [Axes](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#axes).

Comment: Thanks for this. It does work, and you actually just allowed me to clear a big hurdle with xpath and following-sibling.

Answer (score -1):

```
<dl>
        <dt>info</dt>
        <dd>
            <a>a1</a>b2
            <a>a2</a>
        </dd>
    </dl>
```

getting the b2 after  tag. the xpath is like the following.
//dl/dd/a[1]/following-sibling::text()

Comment: KiloJKilo, why don't you select my answer? The key is following-sibling::text(). I just don't tell you the detail answer for your problem.